# Undefined reference to symbol 'BIO_ctrl@@libcrypto.so.10'

Tags: libraries, c++, g++

Hey guys I'm getting a weird g++ compile error while trying to run this C++ file,
here's exact repro steps.

```
# install taglib-devel
$ sudo yum -y install taglib-devel 

$ cd /tmp && git clone https://gist.github.com/1468279.git; cd 1461468279/
$ gcc -g base64.c -lssl -c; 

# install cmake
$ sudo yum install cmake 
$ cd /tmp

# install taglib again =/
$ git clone git@github.com:taglib/taglib.git && cd taglib
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_RELEASE_TYPE=Release .; make; sudo make install

$ cd /tmp/1461468279 && g++ -g -I. -I/usr/local/include/taglib -L/usr/local/lib -ltag -lssl setcover.cpp -o setcover base64.o


# response
/usr/bin/ld: base64.o: undefined reference to symbol 'BIO_ctrl@@libcrypto.so.10'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'BIO_ctrl@@libcrypto.so.10' is defined in DSO /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This looks like it might be off-topic because it's about programming, and might get better answers on our sister site, [SO]. There's no need to cross-post your question there; I've already voted to have it moved, and if the community thinks you'll get better help there, it'll be moved for you.

Comment: Your OpenSSL header files don't match your OpenSSL libraries. You're specifying `-L/usr/local/lib`, and if you're finding OpenSSL there, you need to specify the corresponding include files in `/usr/local` (with the appropriate `-I` parameter) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think is missing -lcrypto on the command that you put